# share option not working in Marshmallow

Tags: android

I wrote this share code as my old code wasnt working in marshmallow. I clearly messed it up and getting no result. if there is any other easy way of sharing images from url please let me know.

```
public void share(View view){
    niv1 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgNetwork);
    File file = getLocalBitmapFile(niv1);
    Uri bmpUrii = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.myfileprovider", file);
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUrii);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "share");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Datas.Address);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
        } 

 public File getLocalBitmapFile(NetworkImageView imageView) {

    Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    File bmpUri = null;

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
    try {
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return file;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.myfileprovider", new File(String.valueOf(niv1)))
```

`niv1` is a `NetworkImageView`. It is not a file path, nor does it point to a file path.

Replace `new File(String.valueOf(niv1))` with a `File` object pointing to a file in a location that is being managed by `FileProvider`, based on your XML metadata. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.1/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) illustrates using `FileProvider`, though in this case it is for a PDF and `ACTION_VIEW`.

Comment: i changed it a bit. please help me

Comment: i changed the code in question ,please tell me where i need to edit it.

Comment: @Sreepulari: You are writing the bitmap to `DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`. That is not where you are telling `FileProvider` the file is -- you are using `DIRECTORY_PICTURES` there. Rename `getLocalBitmapUri()` to `getLocalBitmapFile()`. Have it return the `File` object where you are saving the bitmap. Use that same `File` object with `getUriForFile()`.

Comment: changed the code. please have a look. if you could please edit my question. i'm a total noob.

Comment: @Sreepulari: As I wrote, have `getLocalBitmapFile()` return the `File` object. You do not need it to return a `Uri`. Then, pass that `File` object into `getUriForFile()`, rather than creating a new different `File` object. As it stands, `"share_image_"` is not the same as `"share"`, and the two `System.currentTimeMillis()` calls may result in different values. For this little bit of work, you should only need **one** `File` object.

Comment: changed it, but now its crashing.